# AttributeError: 'Axes' object has no attribute 'get_proj' in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am making the representation of a polynom function.
I have an error in a matplotlib code and cannot understand where it is coming from. any advice is welcome. 
I tried already Gtk3agg but nothing changed.
Below is the failure code.
For any reason 'get_proj' dont work here for creating labels. 
And: when I use ax.get_proj() instead, 
a) all labels appear bottom left
b) not all labels appear at bottom left (all points are identified by the cursor bot the labels are not written at the bottom left).

The final project will be (few things still to be done):
- on button -> labelling with coordinate appear at each cursor movement (temporary)
- click right button, the labels will be persistent till button clear is clicked
- off button -> no labelling appear

My feeling: the 3x button creation is messing anything up.

[image]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d import proj_transform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import numpy as np

mpl.use('tkagg')

def distance(point, event):
    plt.sca(ax)     # <------------------ introduce this one  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    x2, y2, _ = proj_transform(point[0], point[1], point[2], plt.gca().get_proj())
    x3, y3 = ax.transData.transform((x2, y2))
    return np.sqrt ((x3 - event.x)**2 + (y3 - event.y)**2)

def calcClosestDatapoint(X, event):
    distances = [distance(X[i, 0:3], event) for i in range(Sol)]
    return np.argmin(distances)
#
def annotatePlot(X, index):
    global last_mark, generated_labels
    if activated_labelling:

        x2, y2, _ = proj_transform(X[index, 0], X[index, 1], X[index, 2], ax.get_proj())
        last_mark = plt.annotate(generated_labels[index],
            xy = (x2, y2), xytext = (-20, 20), textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
            bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
            arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))

        fig.canvas.draw()
#
def onMouseMotion(event):
    global Coord
    if activated_labelling:
        closestIndex = calcClosestDatapoint(Coord, event)
        last_mark.remove()
        annotatePlot(Coord, closestIndex)       

def show_on(event):
    global activated_labelling, last_mark,pid,mid

    if activated_labelling == False:
        activated_labelling = True
        x2, y2, _ = proj_transform(Coord[0,0], Coord[0,1], Coord[0,2], ax.get_proj())

        last_mark = plt.annotate("3D measurement on " + generated_labels[0],
                    xy = (x2, y2), xytext = (-20, 20), textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
        bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))  
        mid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', onMouseMotion)
#
def show_off(event):
    global activated_labelling
    '''
    deactivate the persistent XYZ position labels at the grafic
    '''
    if activated_labelling:
        activated_labelling = False
        last_mark.remove()
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(mid)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
#ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
activated_labelling = False

Wide = 100
Minimum = -50     
ScanLimit = 3  #  searching between o and 3; 4 and 5 are no solutions
Search = 45

Coord=[]

values=[]

generated_labels = []
#
XMin = 0
XMax = 0
YMin = 0
YMax = 0
ZMin = 0
ZMax = 0

# count the solutions found in the scan area defined above
Sol=0

for i in range(Wide+1):
    for j in range(Wide+1):
        for k in range(Wide+1):

            ########################################################################
            ########################################################################
            ####
            ####                   THIS IS THE POLYNOM TO BE REPRESENTED
            ####
            param_dens = ((i+Minimum)**3)+((j+Minimum)**3)+((k+Minimum)**3) -Search

            if abs(param_dens) <= abs(ScanLimit):
                Coord.append([i+Minimum,j+Minimum,k+Minimum])

                if ScanLimit !=0:
                    values.append([abs(param_dens)])

                labelling = "value {}\nin   X:{}   Y:{}   Z:{}".format(Search+param_dens,i+Minimum,j+Minimum,k+Minimum)    
                generated_labels.append(labelling)
                print(labelling+"\n")

# increase the number indicating the solutions found
                Sol +=1           
# for centering the window          
                if XMin > i+Minimum:
                    XMin = i+Minimum
                if YMin > j+Minimum:
                    YMin = j+Minimum   
                if ZMin > k+Minimum:
                    ZMin = k+Minimum

                if XMax < i+Minimum:
                    XMax = i+Minimum
                if YMax < j+Minimum:
                    YMax = j+Minimum                 
                if ZMax < k+Minimum:
                    ZMax = k+Minimum

print('######################################################')
print('## statistics / move this to a parallel search engine?')
print('## search ')
print("##   total solution %d for searching center %d" % (Sol,Search))    
print("##   from %d to %d" % (Search-ScanLimit,Search+ScanLimit))
print("##   from %d to %d" % (Minimum,Wide+Minimum))      
print('##')      
print('#######################################################')
#
values = np.array(values, dtype='int64')    
Coord = np.array(Coord, dtype='int64')          
#

if ScanLimit !=0:

    cmap = plt.cm.jet  # define the colormap
# extract all colors from the .jet map
    cmaplist = [cmap(i) for i in range(cmap.N)]
# force the first color entry to be black
    cmaplist[0] = (0, 0, 0, 1.0)
# create the new map
    cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom cmap', cmaplist, cmap.N)

# define the bins and normalize
    bounds = np.linspace(0, ScanLimit, ScanLimit+1)
    norm = mpl.colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)
# create a second axes for the colorbar
    ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.1, 0.03, 0.8])
    cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax2, cmap=cmap, norm=norm,
        spacing='proportional', ticks=bounds, boundaries=bounds, format='%1i')

#    
ax.set_xlim3d(XMin-5, XMax+5)
ax.set_ylim3d(YMin-5, YMax+5)
ax.set_zlim3d(ZMin-5, ZMax+5)
#
ax.set_xlabel('X X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Z')

ax.set_aspect(aspect=1)

# extract the scatterplot drawing in a separate function so we ca re-use the code
def draw_scatterplot():
    if ScanLimit !=0:
        ax.scatter3D(Coord[:,0], Coord[:,1], Coord[:,2], s=20, c=values[:,0], cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    else:
        ax.scatter3D(Coord[:,0], Coord[:,1], Coord[:,2], s=20, c='green')

# draw the initial scatterplot
draw_scatterplot()

# create the "on" button, and place it somewhere on the screen
ax_on = plt.axes([0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.05])
button_on = Button(ax_on, 'on')
#
ax_off = plt.axes([0.12, 0.0, 0.1, 0.05])
button_off = Button(ax_off, 'off')
#
#ax_off = plt.axes([0.24, 0.0, 0.1, 0.05])
#button_off = Button(ax_off, 'off')

# link the event handler function to the click event on the button
button_on.on_clicked(show_on)
button_off.on_clicked(show_off)

#fig.colorbar(img)
plt.show()








Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 388, in process
    proxy(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 228, in __call__
    return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/../Desktop/heat.py", line 137, in onClick
    closestIndex,LowestDistance = calcClosestDatapoint(Coord, event)
  File "C:/Users/../Desktop/heat.py", line 50, in calcClosestDatapoint
    distances = [distance(X[i, 0:3], event) for i in range(Sol)]
  File "C:/Users/../Desktop/heat.py", line 50, in <listcomp>
    distances = [distance(X[i, 0:3], event) for i in range(Sol)]
  File "C:/Users/../Desktop/heat.py", line 35, in distance
    x2, y2, _ = proj_transform(point[0], point[1], point[2], plt.gca().get_proj())
AttributeError: 'Axes' object has no attribute 'get_proj'
```

Comment: You are correct thinking that it is your buttons that are messing everything up. When `distance()` is called, `plt.gca()` returns the *current axes*, which is `ax_off`, since it is the last one created. Since this is not a 3D Axes, it does not have a `get_proj()` function. As you had figured it out, you need to write `ax.get_proj()`. If you want someone to help you figure out why the labels don't show up at the right position, you need to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the dirty code and poor posting (not a specialist.. copy/pasting between pycharm and geany and..). I founf out by eliminating the buttons, the ax2 is messing around, too (the labels are appearing at the bottom of the color axes at the right bottom). I have to rethink the whole dramaturgy of my project. Thanks for the commenting.

Comment: adding plt.sca(ax) made it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: final working code posted

Comment: final comment for later search  "script for showing values of 3D X Y Z function coordinates via interactiv labels at mouse position inclusiv buttons on/off"